# ob_start(): second array member is not a valid method

Tags: php

Pegamos hoje um sistema desenvolvido pelo PHPNuke. Ao analisar, vimos que a versão é antiga, porém o cliente está irredutível em desenvolver um novo site, então temos que trabalhar em cima desse existente. O problema é que no servidor está dando o erro **HTTP ERROR 500**. Abrimos o log e o erro que aparece é:

> ob_start(): second array member is not a valid method

O bloco do código está dessa forma:

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) {
        if (extension_loaded('zlib')) {
            $do_gzip_compress = true;
            ob_start(array('ob_gzhandler',5)); // Essa é a linha
            ob_implicit_flush(0);
        //  if (ereg("MSIE", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            if (preg_match("/MSIE/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
            }
        }
    }
```

A versão do PHP é **PHP Version 5.6.40**. Como posso corrigir isso? Observem que existe também uma condicional comentada, pois esse foi o primeiro erro que apareceu e fiz o ajuste.

Comment: Já verificou a documentação desta função? O que seria o segundo parâmetro?

Comment: Olá Anderson. Sim, ele parece que ativa o buffer de saída, porém não sei como ajustá-lo dentro do PHPNuke, pois nunca trabalhei com o PHPNuke.

Comment: muda por `
ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', 5);
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
`

Comment: Olá Adir. Agora deu esse erro: `ob_start(): output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in /home/user/public_html/mainfile.php on line 83`

Answer (score 0):

o que esse funcao faz eh compactar o conteudo em gz para ser enviado ao cliente.

Acontece que essa chamada nao esta correta:

```
ob_start(array('ob_gzhandler',5));
```

Acredito que a intencao original era compactar o conteudo com o nivel de compressao 5.
Uma possivel solucao seria chamar somente o `ob_gzhandler` que sera usado o valor padrao da zlib

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

Ou voce seta o nivel compressao desejado

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', 5);
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

Para evitar esse tipo de confusao no futuro voce pode refatorar o codigo, usar nomes melhores e deixar mais claro o que voce esta fazendo

Comment: Infelizmente também não funcionou. Retornou agora: `output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in /home/user/public_html/mainfile.php on line 84`

Comment: veja o que tem nessa linha, provavelmente voce vai ter que retirar o ini_set antes do ob_start

Comment: Nada... continua dando o mesmo erro :(

Comment: Se o web server que voce esta usando ja fizer a compressao vai conflitar com o do PHP, se esse for o caso vai ter que mudar a configuracao do php para desabilitar o zlib `zlib.output_compression = Off`

Comment: Infelizmente ainda nao funcionou, o erro 500 continua, porém parou de gerar erros no log. Será que é algum tipo de incompatibilidade do servidor com o PHPNuke por ele ser um pouco antigo?

Comment: dificil saber sem a messagem de erro, tenta nao utilizar o ob_gzhandler